# How to set a line at the bottom of the window and don't print carrige return when using "read value"?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm working on a little bash chat. So I would like to have at the bottom of the window, a line where the user can input his message. When he press "enter" the message is sent and print right above the last line. This line must'n move ! like this

```
User A sent: xxxx
User B sent: xxxx
User C sent: xxxx
User A sent: xxxx
User B sent: xxxx
Write your message here : YYYY  *hit enter*
================================================
User A sent: xxxx
User B sent: xxxx
User C sent: xxxx
User A sent: xxxx
User B sent: xxxx
You: YYYY
Write your message here :
```

I use `read userinput` to get the input but a line break appears when he presses "enter" to send his message.

So I tried this:

`echo -e "\033[2A"; #cursor up 2 lines;    echo -en "\r$i"; #remove carriage returns;`

I wrote "Hello" and "Bye" here's what's going on ! I don't know how to solve the problem. Somebody's got a solution ? Thanks

```
Helloge: Hello
Byesage: Bye
message:
```

Answer (score 1):

I advise you take a look into [Cursor Movement](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html) . What you need is to move the cursor to the right `\033[9C` like so:

```
echo -e "\033[2A\033[9C$var_with_text_here"
```

If this isn't really what you need, then please explain better and I'll edit my answer :)

Example:

```
[user@host ~]$ echo "Message: bla"
Message: Hello
[user@host ~]$ echo -e "\033[2A\033[9CHello"
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the slider movements and I changed your code a little bit and got what I wanted.

```
while true; do
echo -e "message: \c"
read usermess
echo -e "\033[1A\033[1D====>  Your message: $usermess"
done
```

Output:

```
====>  Your message: Hello
====>  Your message: Hey
message: Welcome
```

Thank you for your feedback